# If Age is Between 2 Numbers?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to direct users to different content based on their age. I'm trying to direct people older than 35 to `.if_one`, 24-34 to `if_two` and 18-24 to `if_three`..  what do I add to check if they are between 18-24 or 25-34?

Here is what I have so far:

```
$("#age").blur(function() {
    $('.a1, .a2').hide();
    var age = parseInt($('#age').val());
    if (age > 35)
    {
        $('.if_one').show();
        $('#a1').text(age);
        alert($('#a1').val());
    }
    else
    {
        $('.if_two').show();
        $('#a1').text(age);
    }
});
```

Comment: Use `else if`? That's a pretty fundamental part of the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use an if statement with many clauses, and you can use the fact they will be tested in a specific order to your benefit.  If you get the second clause, you can assume the first did not trigger, and therefore must not be true.

```
if (age > 35) {
  // triggers if age is over 35
} else if (age > 24) {
  // age is not over 35, so triggers if between 24 and 35
} else if (age > 18) {
  // age is not over 24, so triggers if between 18 and 24
} else {
  // age is not over 18, so triggers if younger than 18
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
if (age > 35) {
    //...
} else if (age >= 24 && age <= 35) {
    //...
} else if (age >= 18 && age <= 23) {
    //...
} else {
    //age is 17 or less, don't know if you want to do something here...
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `&& age <= 34` and the `&& age <= 23`